# Database vs static html files for storage solution (Site Builder)

Tags: database, file, asp.net-mvc-4, storage

**Project Description:**
As a learning exercise for asp mvc 4, I'm creating a site builder / multitenancy site. It's nothing too fancy just wysiwyg editing on templates with custom routing to direct users to the correct template based on subdomain. So usr1.mysite.com is directed to the template edited by usr1. My main concern at the moment is my method of storing the edited templates.

**Storage Dilemma:**
At first I was simply going to make the templates into views and store the changes made by the user in the database. When usr1's template was displayed the system would pull up the view and populate it with usr1's data.

Instead I've implemented a system that takes the user's modified template and saves the whole thing as static html files in the file system. Only the path to the usr1's site (and some other details) are saved in the database. When usr1.mysite.com is called I just have a "content" controller to retrieve the correct html file.

**Question:**
Is there any reason to choose the database/view method over the static html file method? 
Also I'm not concerned with having dynamic content in the end user pages. This is one reason I even tried the file method.

**Decision (EDIT):**
I'm implementing the file method. After more research (verifying my previous research), I have few doubts the file system will have trouble with even a few hundred sites. I will structure it in a way to group user data directories into group directories based on a naming convention I've yet to dream up, probably something like 000usr1, 000usr2 in 000 group directory. With a goal of less than 100 files/folders in any given directory and less than 4 levels deep. Which should give me the capability of holding 10000 sites. I have no plans of having any activity near that level with this software, but I do want to get up and running and torture it for awhile and see what it's capable of handling. If anyone expresses any interest I'll post back some results.

Comment: Files are typically much more less expensive in terms of memory, cpu, and I/O then Databases.  Databases are much more friendly in terms of adding features (versioning, auditing, etc).  Pick your poison wisely :)

Comment: It's a tough decision. I'm favoring the file method for now since I already have it in place, but I do wonder how maintainable it would be if it turned into a project that went beyond a personal learning exercise.